# Register Windows Runtime Component (c++winrt) in native c++ application

Tags: c++, audio, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

Native c++ application is using c++/winrt classes to instantiate and use `winrt::Windows::Media::Audio::AudioGraph`. 
Inside `AudioGraph` there is possibility to add effects to graph nodes. There are some already created effects (like echo effect) but there is also possibility to create custom audio effect. 
Custom audio effect class must be a `Windows Runtime Component`. There is a way to create custom audio effect in Windows Runtime Component c++/winrt project by creating class with `Windows.Media.Effects.IBasicAudioEffect` interface in idl file (and providing implementation). This generates winmd, lib and winrt headers files. 
Until this point everything is fine and working. But to instantiate audio effect it need to be registered and this steep I am missing. Application at runtime throw's an exception with "Class not registered" message when I want to instantiate audio effect class and also throw an exception "Failed to activate audio effect" when I want to instantiate it inside `AudioGraph` node.

I do not know how to registered Windows Runtime Component from native c++ application.

Steps to create and use custom audio effect are describe here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-audio-effects. Code is in C# and used in UWP application but it could be converted to c++/winrt almost 1:1.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/425) describe the same problem?

Comment: @IInspectable It's similar problem, but my application is native c++. I will check if the given solution will work for me.

Comment: @IInspectable Tank you link you provided give me a clue what to look for ("reg-free winrt activation").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article solves this problem:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/

It is possible to use Registration-free WinRT (starting from Windows 10 1903) by modifying application manifest file (and not Windows Runtime Component Package manifest as suggested in documentation) like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
 
  <file name="WinRTComponent.dll">
    <activatableClass
        name="WinRTComponent.Class1"
        threadingModel="both"
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1" />
    <activatableClass
        name="WinRTComponent.Class2"
        threadingModel="both"
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1" />
  </file>
 
</assembly>
```